# php Multiple dimension array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I'm using an array to parse some information through Jquery.

First of all the script search in the db for quotes like the user has searched for.

Then it send these information to an array, however when output the data the site doesnt respond back anything at all.

```
$check_faqs = "
SELECT 
    faq_title, 
    faq_url, 
    faq_content, 
    chapter_id 
FROM 
    faqs 
WHERE 
    faq_content LIKE '%". $search ."%'
AND faq_status != 'deleted'
";
$query_faqs = mysqli_query($con, $check_faqs);

if (mysqli_num_rows($query_faqs) !== 0) { 

    $faqs = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_faqs)) {
        $chapter_info = array();
        $query_chapter = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT chapter_title, chapter_url FROM faqs_chapters WHERE chapter_id = '". $row["chapter_id"] ."'");
        $chapter = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_chapter);
        array_push($chapter_info, $chapter["chapter_title"]);
        array_push($chapter_info, $chapter["chapter_url"]);
        array_push($row, $chapter_info);
        $faqs[] = $row;
    }
    $count_faqs = mysqli_num_rows($query_faqs);
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'faqsCount' => $count_faqs, 'faqs' => $faqs));
    die($output);

}
```

When i output the data incl. a var_dump i receive an perfect array of the data i need. Howver without a var_dump no arrays is avalaible in the output?

Here the code incl. the var_dump

```
$check_faqs = "...
    }
    print_r($faqs);
    $count_faqs = mysqli_num_rows($query_faqs);
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'faqsCount' => $count_faqs, 'faqs' => $faqs));
    die($output);
```

Here's the print info:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [faq_title] => test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner
            [faq_url] => test
            [faq_content] => test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner
            [chapter_id] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Private brugere
                    [1] => private-brugere
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [faq_title] => test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner
            [faq_url] => test-two2
            [faq_content] => test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner
            [chapter_id] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Private brugere
                    [1] => private-brugere
                )

        )

)
```

Frayne Konok : `echo "<pre>"; print_r($faqs); echo "</pre>";`

```
 <pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [faq_title] => test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner
            [faq_url] => test
            [faq_content] => test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner
            [chapter_id] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Private brugere
                    [1] => private-brugere
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [faq_title] => test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner
            [faq_url] => test-two2
            [faq_content] => test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner
            [chapter_id] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Private brugere
                    [1] => private-brugere
                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

Comment: use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($output); die;` to print your array ..

Comment: what is your actual question?? Want to know the value of `$faqs`?? This is an array, so you have to use a `print_r` to show like an array.

Comment: i just want it to save the values to the output.

Comment: However the $output returns empty

Comment: Here `$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'faqsCount' => $count_faqs, 'faqs' => $faqs));` change `'faqs' => $faqs` to `'faqs' => array($faqs)`

Comment: Just tried: array($faqs) still no output :S

Comment: after your while loop use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($faqs) echo "</pre>";` and copy the output and post to this question.

Comment: Updated the question with the response

Comment: okey wait for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Online link](https://3v4l.org/WhoBU)

**Suppose you have an array**

```
$faqs = array(
            array(
                "faq_title" =>  "test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner",
                "faq_url" => "test",
                "faq_content" => "test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner",
                "chapter_id" => 1,
                array("Private brugere", "private-brugere")
            ),
            array(
                "faq_title" => "test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner",
                "faq_url" => "test",
                "faq_content" => "test af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr�ve p� andre funktioner",
                "chapter_id" => 2,
                array("Private brugere", "private-brugere")
            )
    );
```

**Count the array**

```
$count_faqs = count($faqs);
```

**Encode the array**

```
$output = json_encode(array('type' => 'success',  'faqsCount' => $count_faqs, 'faqs' => $faqs));
```

**Output**

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Result**

```
{"type":"success","faqsCount":2,"faqs":[{"faq_title":"test af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktioner","faq_url":"test","faq_content":"test af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktioner","chapter_id":1,"0":["Private brugere","private-brugere"]},{"faq_title":"test af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktioner","faq_url":"test","faq_content":"test af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktionertest af en eller anden pr\ufffdve p\ufffd andre funktioner","chapter_id":2,"0":["Private brugere","private-brugere"]}]}
```